# Jbutton, JPanel, JFrame and IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

Tags: swing, jframe, awt, jpanel, jbutton

I have a JFrame and multiple JPanels, all called from public class ProcessedFinal extends JFrame, in here, i have all my action listeners including the IAgreeJB. When i click the iagreeJB the PlayGameJP is supposed to set visible. It worked, when i called the exit JPanel (ExitJP), now when i call a new JPanel (PlayGameJP) i am getting this error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

It makes no sense for me since i am just substituting one JPanel for another, what can be the reason?

```
   if ( e.getSource() == ComputeRegistrationJP.IAgreeJB )
           {    



remove(ComputeRegistrationJP);
setVisible( false );

add( ExitJP );
setVisible(true);



  // add( PlayGameJP );
  // setVisible( true );

 }
```

nevermind pals, i was extending JFrame instead of JPanel in my PlayGameJP, it was all.

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions for you! :)

> *... i have all my action listeners including the IAgreeJB...*

Does this have anything to do with the question ?

> *...now when i call a new JPanel (PlayGameJP) i am getting this error :...*

As far as I know there is NO constructor for [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) like `JPanel (javax.swing.JPanel)` ,Assuming `PlayGameJP` is  a JPanel. So in this case the error you must get is :

`no suitable constructor found for JPanel(javax.swing.JPanel)`

---

Being said these, what does the code you posted have to do with the question you wrote?

---

For better sooner help, I'd suggest you to rephrase the question and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your best attempt. or the relevant code.

---

For the error message you posted,

> *...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container...*

I've seen this when you try to add a top level container to another, say add a `JDialog` to a `JFrame`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was a dumb mistake. i was extending JFrame instead of JPanel in my PlayGameJP, everything was declared and defined just fine.